# How to map the Delete key in vimrc?

Tags: vim

On an old UNIX workstation, Freebsd 3.6 (I know 3.6 is old, but it isn't connected to network), my Vim doesn't have the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key mapped.

So I did

```
:set <del>=(pressed CTRL-V)(pressed delete/canc)
```

This works, but I don't know the correct syntax for `vimrc`

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> in a terminal I can see that my <kbd>Delete</kbd> key sends `^[[3~`.  So I tried adding

```
map <DEL> ^[[3~
```

to my `.vimrc`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it the other way around:

```
map <Esc>[3~    <Del>
```

Or use `t_kD` instead:

```
let &t_kD = "\x1b[3~"
```